# How to handle completion of many asynchronous callbacks

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-sql

I have a local WebSQL db that I need to sync with a remote MySQL server. To do so, I have split the process into multiple requests, so I can fire the callback in between every request to show the progress.

The problem is that I have serious race conditions here that I don't think I can solve with the callbacks, because the insert statements are within a $.each() function (aka for loop).

I have this asynchronous problem spread all over the database interface. I have been investigating how to use promises and Deferred in jQuery, but that doesn't seem to solve the problem. I just need to make this thing synchronous.

```
evalua.webdb.sync = function(callback){ 
$.getJSON("index.php/get/sync_riesgo",function(data){
    evalua.webdb.db.transaction(function(tx){
        $(data.riesgos).each(function(index, value){
            tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO riesgos (idRiesgo, nombre) VALUES ("'+value.idRiesgo+'", "'+value.nombre+'")');
        });
        $(data.estancias).each(function(index, value){
            tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO estancias (idEstancia, nombre, dimensionMinima) VALUES ("'+value.idEstancia+'", "'+value.nombre+'", "'+value.dimensionMinima+'")');
        });
        $(data.riesgosestancias).each(function(index, value){
            tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO riesgosestancias (idRiesgoEstancia, idRiesgo, idEstancia, porcentaje, indispensable) VALUES ("'+value.idRiesgoEstancia+'", "'+value.idRiesgo+'", "'+value.idEstancia+'", "'+value.porcentaje+'", "'+value.indispensable+'")');
        });
    });
});
    callback("First one done");
$.getJSON("index.php/get/sync_operaciones",function(data){
    evalua.webdb.db.transaction(function(tx){
        $(data.companhias).each(function(index, value){
            tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO companhias (idCompanhia, nombre) VALUES ("'+value.idCompanhia+'", "'+value.nombre+'")');
        });
        $(data.operaciones).each(function(index, value){
            tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO operaciones (idOperacion, nombre, descripcion) VALUES ("'+value.idOperacion+'", "'+value.nombre+'", "'+value.descripcion+'")');
        });
    });
});
    callback("Second one done");
}
```

Comment: If its about the async, how can you be sure about " callback("First one done"); ? It can happen that the 2. callback finishes first , cuz of any reason

Comment: @Vury that's why I need to run executeSql as a synchronous, blocking function. The code above doesn't work because there's race conditions everywhere. It's an example of what I want to have working

Comment: If you have a dependency that the second call needs to complete after the first you need to execute the second call on completion/success of the first one.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl I know, but I can't simply fire a callback in the first .getJSON(), because executeSql is also asynchronous, so I never know when it's finished. I could fire the callback upon AJAX request completion, and let the SQL statements finish themselves. But I have foreign keys, so race conditions here kill it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I may have found a solution right here:

[HTML5 WebSQL: how to know when a db transaction finishes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7607677/html5-websql-how-to-know-when-a-db-transaction-finishes?rq=1)

I still need to know how to make different INSERT statements, and to handle the promises one after another. But that's a smaller set of chained callbacks.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery ajax has a setting to make ajax requests synchronous.  Very easy to do

```
$.ajaxSetup({'async': false});
```

...or just use `.ajax` and set this individually with each request.

If you want the requests as a whole to be asynchronous but fire in order, you have to create a queue of some kind: https://gist.github.com/3818056 -- doesn't use the Deferred API, though it probably could.  You would use it as follows:

```
var aq = new AjaxQueue();
aq.push({'type': 'get', 'dataType': 'json', 'url': 'index.php/get/sync_riesgo',
   'success': "you're really long function"});
aq.push({'type': 'get', 'dataType': 'json', 'url': 'index.php/get/sync_operaciones',
   'success': "you're really long function"});
```

Of course, this *also* requires the client to continue running until the continue running until the ajax queue is empty.  If available, I would suggest doing:

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function () {
   if (aq.q.length) {
      return "Still doing back end processing; please stay on page for a moment";
   }
});
```

Comment: Thanks! That solves the problem with the ajax calls, but the main issue is with the SQL queries, also asynchronous and within a for loop.

Comment: As a side-note for OP: while `async: false` may solve the issue, please note that this will hang/freeze your browser until the calls are completed, which may not be very user friendly.

Comment: Why shouldn't you use the deferred api? This usually works beautifully for handling cases such as waiting for multiple async operations to complete.