# Retrieving a specific item from SQLite database

Tags: javascript, android, sqlite, jquery-mobile

I have here a broken function code that would retrieve a specific item from the SQLite database, my problem is I want to pass the value of the retrieved item to displayContent but I do not know how to do it, my code is only designed to retrieve a single row not multiple rows as the contents of SecondColumn are not identical. I am clueless right now.

Here is my code:

```
function ( content )
{
    var displayContent;
    db.transaction(function (tx) { tx.executeSql('SELECT FirstColumn FROM SampleTable WHERE SecondColumn = ?',[content]); });
}
```

Any additional ideas will be gladly accepted, I am stuck with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `tx.executeSql` method takes a callback where you can then process the results of the query.  Have a look here and you can see an example: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/html5/html5_web_sql.htm

As you can see there, they do the following:

```
db.transaction(function (tx) {
  tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM LOGS', [], function (tx, results) {
   var len = results.rows.length, i;
   msg = "<p>Found rows: " + len + "</p>";
   document.querySelector('#status').innerHTML +=  msg;
   for (i = 0; i < len; i++){
     msg = "<p><b>" + results.rows.item(i).log + "</b></p>";
     document.querySelector('#status').innerHTML +=  msg;
   }
 }, null);
});
```

In your case you'd probably do something like this:

```
function ( content )
{
    db.transaction(function (tx) {
        tx.executeSql('SELECT FirstColumn FROM SampleTable WHERE SecondColumn = ?',[content], function (tx, results) {
            if (results.rows.length) {
                var displayContent = results.rows.item(0).FirstColumn;
                document.querySelector('...').innerHTML = ...; // Display something
            }
        });
    });
}
```

If you want to try to wait for the query, have a look at this previous Stackoverflow question: [HTML5 WebSQL: how to know when a db transaction finishes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7607677/html5-websql-how-to-know-when-a-db-transaction-finishes)

Comment: Thanks alot, everything is clear to me now. I just tested it in my app and it works.